# If $f\in C[0,2\pi]$ and $f(0)=f(2\pi)$ then $f(\theta)=f(\theta+\pi)$ for some $\theta\,\in\,(0,\pi)$?

Tags: real-analysis, periodic-functions

> If $f\in C[0,2\pi]$ and $f(0)=f(2\pi)$ then $f(\theta)=f(\theta+\pi)$ for some $\theta\,\in\,(0,\pi)$?

Intuitively I think it's wrong, but I failed to come up with a single counterexample. Can anybody give a hint for proving or disproving it?

Comment: $C^1$? What for?

Comment: As Did already mentioned, your assumptions of a $C^1$ $f$ are to strong. You only need continuity. What for theorems (with names) do you know for continuous functions? By the way. Your statement implies that you can find antipodal points on the equator with same temperature.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 Thx, I revised it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x)=\sin x$$

It's continuous and $f(0) = f(2 \pi)$, but there exists no $\theta \in (0, \pi)$ such that $f(\theta)=f(\theta+\pi)$.